# File search with a lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I apologize in advance for this one but it's late where I'm at and I'm tired. I have a simple problem to solve but I just can't come up with the answer. I have two criteria: 1) find files in a directory where the filename matches a certain criteria  and 2) only consider files that have a creation time for today. There's lots of posts about both of those criteria but none that have them put together. Here's the code I've mashed together (be nice to me, please).

```
string fooDay = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
string fooMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
string fooYear = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
List<string> T340Basics = new List<string>();
T340Basics = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\10.0.0.73\shared\340B\340Basics\OUT\out_archive", @"340B_Captured_Claim_File*.txt").Where(a => (a.CreationTime.Month == fooMonth && a.CreationTime.Day == fooDay && a.CreationTime.Year == fooYear)).ToList();
```

This errors out on the CreationTime parts of the Lambda expression, the error is : string does not contain a definition for 'CreationTime'and no extension method 'CreationTime' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found.

Like I said, I know this one has to be simple, I just can't figure it out. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can't you do `a.CreationTime.Date = DateTime.Now.Date` ?

Comment: `fooDay` is a string,  `CreationTime.Year` is not. You can't compare them with `==`

Comment: The problem is that the references to a.CreationTime gives me the error I listed in my original description.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DirectoryInfo` instead of the static `Directory.GetFiles` because `GetFiles` (on `DirectoryInfo`) returnes an `FileInfo[]` instead of an `string[]`.

Use it like this:

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\10.0.0.73\shared\340B\340Basics\OUT\out_archive");

if(info.Exists)
{
   info.GetFiles(@"340B_Captured_Claim_File*.txt", <OptionalSearchOption>).Where(file => file.CreationDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).ToList(); 
}
```

You can also shorten your pattern like this:

```
file => file.CreationDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
```

Just compare the two Dates (sets the Time components to 00:00:000 in both DateTime objects).

Comment: the problem is that there are quite a few files in this directory so I wanted to keep the looping to a minimum. If info.GetFiles gives me some way to filter on my criteria I posted above, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Just try it out ! There are almost the same options as in `Directory.GetFile()` you can also set a `SearchPattern` and some `SearchOptions` here too.